# UITableViewCell - layoutSubview with adaptable view height for text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

When I create my own `UITableViewCell` I use `layoutSubviews` to arrange the elements in the cell.
However, how can I create an area that is adaptable to the required numbers of lines - depending on how long the description text is.

```
-(void) layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(8.0, 10.0, 20.0, 20.0)];
    [description setFrame:CGRectMake(40.0, 1.0, 250.0, 40.0)]; //1..n lines  <- ???????

}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        [self.contentView addSubview: imageView];

        titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
        [titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0]];
        [titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [titleLabel setHighlightedTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
        [titleLabel setLineBreakMode: NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        //titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
        [self.contentView addSubview: titleLabel];

        description = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
        [description setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]];
        [description setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
        [description setHighlightedTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
        [description setLineBreakMode: NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        //description.numberOfLines = 1;                     //1..n lines  <- ???????
        [self.contentView addSubview: description];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Table cell doesn't determine it's own height.  Instead UITableView lays out the cells.  Now, `UITableView` does have a delegate method: `- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.  However, it will call that method for each row in the table before the table has displayed it's data (or called the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method).  This is because `UITableView` needs to know how large (or tall) the table will be before it begins displaying the data, as it uses this information to set the contentSize, determine scroll bar heights, etc.  What this means, if you want to have table cells with variable cell heights, you'll need to have calculated those cell heights before the table loads.  If the table is small, then this is no problem, but if your table is large or the calculations complex it could create a delay in displaying your table.  For this reason, you usually want the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` to be very efficient.

But once you've done this (calculated the row heights) you don't need to do anything in your `UITableViewCell` subclass other than layout your subviews.  The cell height will already be set for you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the height of the cell by calculating the size of the string (cell content) that you want to place it in a cell. This calculation should be in:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Once height is calculated you have to then adjust/place frame of elements(cell contents) inside the cell accordingly.